DivisionByZeroError PHP error
I keep getting the following PHP error on a Drupal 9 site that I'm working on that seems to be initiated by the tags taxonomy. I create an article and if I don't add tags it works fine. If I do add tags, it throws the error and then also throws the error on any other page on the whole site that references the tag taxonomy in any way, or so it seems.
Here is the error:
DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero in __TwigTemplate_4301948afb36afa2e9793a4503fa706794eeb4bd84a6bd3267623f7465c3b015->doDisplay() (line 117 of /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(418) : eval()'d code)
#0 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_4301948afb36afa2e9793a4503fa706794eeb4bd84a6bd3267623f7465c3b015->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#1 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#2 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(390): Twig\Template->display(Array)
#3 /code/web/core/themes/engines/twig/twig.engine(55): Twig\Template->render(Array)
#4 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php(384): twig_render_template('modules/compose...', Array)
#5 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(433): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('views_bootstrap...', Array)
#6 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(446): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array)
#7 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(204): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false)
#8 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php(479): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array)
#9 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(418) : eval()'d code(110): Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object(Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment), Array, 'html', NULL, true)
#10 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_63686e547fa77ea05a748061ae6533a30dc9a72e32a52db727266a68bdcab472->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#11 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#12 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(390): Twig\Template->display(Array)
#13 /code/web/core/themes/engines/twig/twig.engine(55): Twig\Template->render(Array)
#14 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php(384): twig_render_template('themes/composer...', Array)
#15 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(433): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('views_view', Array)
#16 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(446): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array)
#17 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(204): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false)
#18 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php(479): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array)
#19 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(418) : eval()'d code(82): Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object(Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment), Array, 'html', NULL, true)
#20 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(182): __TwigTemplate_53894a115bbe9de9d91140a1e71ead2f642de5e1566d87ab434d1050ee683b3e->block_content(Array, Array)
#21 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(418) : eval()'d code(69): Twig\Template->displayBlock('content', Array, Array)
#22 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_53894a115bbe9de9d91140a1e71ead2f642de5e1566d87ab434d1050ee683b3e->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#23 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#24 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(390): Twig\Template->display(Array)
#25 /code/web/core/themes/engines/twig/twig.engine(55): Twig\Template->render(Array)
#26 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php(384): twig_render_template('themes/composer...', Array)
#27 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(433): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('block', Array)
#28 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(446): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array)
#29 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(204): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false)
#30 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php(479): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array)
#31 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(418) : eval()'d code(71): Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object(Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment), Array, 'html', NULL, true)
#32 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_a0a47dab2a46b8de2ff59926bfc58a768edb1722ebb038b8868c0e8c873f1df8->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#33 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#34 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(390): Twig\Template->display(Array)
#35 /code/web/core/themes/engines/twig/twig.engine(55): Twig\Template->render(Array)
#36 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php(384): twig_render_template('modules/compose...', Array)
#37 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(433): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('blb_section', Array)
#38 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(446): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array)
#39 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(446): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array)
#40 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(204): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false)
#41 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php(479): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array)
#42 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(418) : eval()'d code(46): Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object(Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment), Array, 'html', NULL, true)
#43 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_1388ee01fdf16f4fa2481d8c64dbae9e41ce14611bb734e9389a3ab4a6b71a35->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#44 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#45 /code/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(390): Twig\Template->display(Array)
#46 /code/web/core/themes/engines/twig/twig.engine(55): Twig\Template->render(Array)
#47 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php(384): twig_render_template('core/modules/us...', Array)
#48 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(433): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('user', Array)
#49 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(204): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false)
#50 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/HtmlRenderer.php(242): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, false)
#51 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(580): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}()
#52 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/HtmlRenderer.php(243): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure))
#53 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/HtmlRenderer.php(132): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch))
#54 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/MainContentViewSubscriber.php(90): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch))
#55 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ViewEvent), 'kernel.view', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
#56 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(142): call_user_func(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ViewEvent), 'kernel.view', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
#57 /code/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(174): Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ViewEvent), 'kernel.view')
#58 /code/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(81): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#59 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(58): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#60 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(48): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#61 /code/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(106): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#62 /code/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(85): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#63 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(48): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#64 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(51): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#65 /code/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#66 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(718): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#67 /code/web/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#68 {main}

Line 117 is bolded below, which doesn't really mean anything to me:
    public function __construct(LoaderInterface $loader, $options = [])
    {
        $this->setLoader($loader);

        $options = array_merge([
            'debug' => false,
            'charset' => 'UTF-8',
            'base_template_class' => Template::class,
            'strict_variables' => false,
            'autoescape' => 'html',
            'cache' => false,
            'auto_reload' => null,
            'optimizations' => -1,
        ], $options);

        **$this->debug = (bool) $options['debug'];**
        $this->setCharset($options['charset']);
        $this->baseTemplateClass = '\\'.ltrim($options['base_template_class'], '\\');
        if ('\\'.Template::class !== $this->baseTemplateClass && '\Twig_Template' !== $this->baseTemplateClass) {
            @trigger_error('The "base_template_class" option on '.__CLASS__.' is deprecated since Twig 2.7.0.', \E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        }
        $this->autoReload = null === $options['auto_reload'] ? $this->debug : (bool) $options['auto_reload'];
        $this->strictVariables = (bool) $options['strict_variables'];
        $this->setCache($options['cache']);
        $this->extensionSet = new ExtensionSet();

        $this->addExtension(new CoreExtension());
        $this->addExtension(new EscaperExtension($options['autoescape']));
        $this->addExtension(new OptimizerExtension($options['optimizations']));
    }

Any idea what would be causing this? It was not happening last week and then just started causing problems all of the sudden without me updating any modules or core, installing new modules, etc. Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Unfortunately, Drupal doesn't report the real line number and template file where the error occurs. You can change this by removing one line in the core render engine. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/320122/how-to-understand-verbose-log-of-drupal-to-isolate-a-culprit-function-or-templat/320123#320123

Which theme is on the site?

@monalisa Bootstrap 8.x-3.26

Are there any custom templates in the site? Have you tried with the supported versions of Drupal Core and Bootstrap?

@monalisa The OP tried to locate the code line causing the error but couldn't because they looked in the base class instead of the compiled PHP template. The linked answer shows how to locate the correct PHP file or even better, how to get the original Twig error with the Twig code line and full template file name.

I interpreted the Question as "Any idea what would be causing this?", because that is literally what the question says, and although outdated software, including versions of views_bootstrap, have shown exactly this bug—which is the reason I asked for clarification of software versions—the Question is really asking "Why is this line number wrong?".

The question is OK, it has a main topic and a context.

This question is similar to: How to understand verbose log of Drupal to isolate a culprit function or template?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
